# How to keep the value with signs as number from dataframe after write into Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am currently using XlsxWriter to output the dataframe to Excel files.
My dataframe is as follows.

```
Num     Des     price   percentage
321     pencil  $23     24%
452     pen     $12     29%
444     key     $32     33%
111     eraser  $49     14%
```

And the dollar and percent signs I used are by the codes:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.0%')) 
df['percentage'] = df['percentage'].apply(lambda x: format(x, "${:20,.0f}"))
```

But after I output the dataframe into Excel by XlsxWriter, the values with signs turn into strings.

Is there a way that I can keep the number type?

Comment: you can add some new formats to be used by the workbook                        
"percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})"

Comment: @sara what if I want to set decimal precision and % sign on the same column? I tried with #,##0.00% it is calculating the percentage. How do I prevent calculating percentage in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use pandas to format the file, use them for what they 're best at, pandas for the data manipulation and xlsxwriter for the format.

So your code should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num': [321,452,444,111],
                    'Des': ['pencil','pen','key','eraser'],
                    'price': [23,12,32,49],
                    'percentage': [24,29,33,14]})

# Divide by 100 the column with the percentages
df['percentage'] = df['percentage'] / 100

# Pass the df into the xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define the formats
cell_format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0'})
cell_format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

# Set the columns width and format
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 12, cell_format1)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 12, cell_format2)

# Write the file
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

For more info about xlsxwriter's format class have a look [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html), it really has everything you need.

Comment: what if I want to set decimal precision and % sign on the same column?